# How to get Pages info

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Is there any site with info about Manage pages permission within Facebook?
How can I get "pages info" without ManagePages permission?

Answer (score 0):

You can get any page info as long it is public and not restricted to you. Use the page id or the page username through the graph API like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/CocaCola
```